# Ionic App nao acessa o servidor local

Tags: android

Ora viva galera!

Estou desenvolvendo um app ionic e gerei um apk para plataforma android, consegui instalar no meu celular, porem nao consigo ter acesso ao servidor (estou usando o xampp), assim nao consigo efectuar o login para poder usar o app.

**Provider**

```
    @Injectable()
export class AccessProviders {
  server: string = 'http://192.168.43.253/phpp/';
  constructor(
      public http: HttpClient,
      public allertCrtl: AlertController,

  ) {}

  postDate(body, file) {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                });
      let options = {
          headers: headers
      }
      return this.http.post(this.server + 'SubmeterDados.php/'+ file, JSON.stringify(body),
          options).timeout(59000).map(res => res);
  }
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

No navegador, atraves do ionic serve (tanto local como external) tudo funciona, mas o apk nao.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Na verdade, eu criei um app ionic e gerei um apk debug para Android, porém ao instalar o apk no meu celular Android não consigo comunicar com o banco de dados.

Comment: Estou usando o mysql